# Python API to execute remote command through SSH

Tags: python, authentication, ssh-keys, openssh

I want to connect to create a pair of keys, transfer the private key to the remote host, and connect to it using some Python API, so that I can execute a command on the remote host. However, I do not want to require the user to interact with a GUI, so I need to do this all through CLI; the problem is that on Windows I can't find a tool to do this, and plink does not accept keys that are not generated by PuttyGen!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl this might be what I was looking for, but is it possible to do it without puttygen?

Comment: What's wrong is that it doesn't provide a CLI

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much @MartinPrikryl

Answer (score 0):

Just by doing a rapid search, it seems [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) module would be your best course for sending commands via SSH. I don't get the key generation part, though.